# How do i know partial view called from which main view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any way i can know that partial view is called from which main view?

I have one partial view being called from two main views with different data.

```
MainIndex1.cshtml
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_partialView.cshtml", Model)

MainIdex2.cshtml
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_partialView.cshtml", Model)
```

so, in `_partialView` how i can know that it is called from which main view?

Comment: You can use the `ViewBag` for that. `ViewBag.Caller = "MainIndex#";` and check it in your partial view.

Comment: Do i need to pass ViewBag when calling partial view? or it is global can be accessed in partial view?

Comment: Set it in the main view before calling the partial view. You don't have to pass it, it is 'global' as you say it.

Comment: The correct syntax to use view bad @{ ViewBag.Caller = "MainIndex#";}. anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see which controller and action is participating to call this partial view.  So if you want to get the parent context inside this child action you could do this:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    var rd = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData;
    var currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    ...
    return View();
}
```

or you can also use this code to find out the controller and action name for current request.

```
Controller: @ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
<br />
View: @ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue
```

refer following thread on stackoverflow..

[Get the parent controller name from partialview action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511074/get-the-parent-controller-name-from-partialview-action)

hope this will help you.
thanks